# Function arguments not passing to function

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass three variables arguments to function as following:

```
$productName = 'Product';
$details = 'size';
$existingCart = 'Nothing';
$newCart = $this->cartHandler($productName, $details, $existingCart);
```

Handler function:

```
private function cartHandler($productName, $details, $existingCart)
{
     return $details;
}
```

This will return nothing. Same result for returning `$productName` & `$existingCart`. These two functions are in same class.

Comment: Do you have any errors from this function? Checked your Error log?

Comment: I'm post those three variables and I get them successfully. There is no error.

Comment: $details isn't defined at all in your code.

Comment: $details = 'size' ?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, the code seems to work, I'm wondering if it might be something to do with where you have the code in your class.

Comment: This is an api. I can get each of those variables out of cartHandler function. but `$newCart` returns nothing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133757/discussion-between-fluxcoder-and-pka).